# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB text csv file UTF-8 with BOM - Read problem

Tags: csv, utf-8, oledb, byte-order-mark

I have an application in which the user can query data in a text file (e.g. .csv) with ad hoc SQL SELECT statements.  Using ODBC drivers or OLEDB providers (including Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0) to read the files, everything works great except reading UTF-8 encoded files with BOM.  I specify CharacterSet=65001 in the Extended Properties.  It does correctly read the encoded Unicode text from the file.  But it doesn't recognize the 3 byte BOM (EFBBBF in hex) at the start of the file.  It assumes it is just another Unicode character, which it is: U+FEFF (ZWNBS, an unusual character, correctly encoded as 3 bytes in the file - my system cannot display it so a ? is shown).  (If reading file as ANSI/ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8/65001 then the BOM is displayed as ï»¿).  The column names in the .csv file are in the 1st row of the text file.  So the BOM (U+FEFF) gets prepended to the 1st column name (i.e. 1st column gets renamed) - messing things up.  My HACK solution is, if this UTF-8 file does have a BOM, then, when displaying data (e.g. showing results of select * from file1, including the column names), remove the BOM from the 1st column name.  And then add it back when querying for the column.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Actually... the BOM is recognized.  Sorry.  You can query using the first column name with no need to prepend the BOM.  But you can prepend the BOM to the first column name and that also works fine.  However, there is a case in which you need to prepend the BOM (which was my case) - there's space between the BOM and the first column name.  Then you need to query like: SELECT [BOM FirstColumn] FROM File1.  Also- you still usually need to remove the BOM when displaying data with column names.

Comment: Lastly, there seems to be a bug when the query has 2 tables (files) joined and the 2nd table has 2+ spaces at the end of the line with the column names.